# Iframe fullscreen instead of scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I did search to see if there was already an answer and there are some related answers but the code is different. I'm honestly not sure if this is HTML or Javascript. I have no experience with web development.

So this is what is pasted to my WordPress website.

```
<iframe src="https:"some address" style="border:none; min-height: 700px; width: 1px; min-width: 100%; *width: 100%;" name="site" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" width="100%" height="100%" referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OduQD.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO Ermin, First thing you have done a lot of mistake in `html`, if you have done it in hurry than take time to post review question or if not than try some tutorials available on internet

Comment: I didn't create it. It is from an email marketing website that provides you with an embed code after making a landing page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding scrolling `(scrolling="no")` attribute to remove scrolling.

```
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/" style="border:none; height:100vh; width: 100%;" name="site" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" width="100%" height="100%" referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

as `scrolling` is deprecated I guess then we should go with CSS.

you can add this in your styleSheet or inside `<style>` tag in HTML page

```
iframe {
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-Y:hidden;
}
```

Comment: The `scrolling` attr is deprecated.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: That did get rid of the scrolling, but I want the landing page to take up the fullscreen. Since the scrolling is gone now, I can't see the entire landing page (the content). It was my goal from the beginning to make the landing page fullscreen so the scrolling was not there (or visible).

Comment: I have added height=100vh this should solve your full-screen issue. Do check!!

Comment: Do you mean on top of what you already suggested or by itself? because it does not change anything by itself.

Comment: copy the <iframe> code again, I have made some inline CSS changes in it.

Comment: That is much better! The only problem is that it still does not take up the entire page. It is centered, all the content is showing, no scrolling, but everything is stretched to fit the whole page in the original. In my case, it is not stretched to fit the entire page.

Comment: can you post the original and current screenshots? It will give us a proper understanding of the scenerio

Comment: https://ibb.co/j5fKtkh Here you are. As you see it does not stretch out to the whole page, it is just centered.

Comment: it looks like your <iframe> has a parent element maybe <div> or something, I need to see that!! Can you put your complete HTML code or at least code inside <body> tag

Comment: looks like custom CSS, remove all the <div> just put <body> <iframe> code </body> see if it helps!!

Comment: I got it to work. I could not simply delete it, it caused some really odd changes..BUT, since you let me know it was likely related to my WordPress Theme..I went to Customize the theme and made that specific page with the landing page Full page.

Comment: cool, glad to help